# MS Access : Query to add "If" condition

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following MS Access Query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Version_Change AS a
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT VERSION,
          min(ChangeDate) AS minimumdate,
          ObjectID
   FROM Version_Change
   GROUP BY ObjectID,
            VERSION) AS b ON(a.VERSION = b.VERSION)
AND (a.ChangeDate = b.minimumdate)
AND (a.ObjectID = b.ObjectID);
```

The **problem** is that the column "ChangeDate" can sometimes be blank.So I would like my query to show also the fields where "ChangeDate" is Null. How can I integrate this condition in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If change dates, for one version and objectid, are all `NULL` then `min(ChangeDate)` will be null also, and the join won't succeed because `a.ChangeDate = NULL` will be evaluated to NULL which is not true.

You can change the ON condition like this:

```
ON (a.version = b.version)
   AND
   (
     (a.ChangeDate = b.minimumdate)
     OR
     (a.ChangeDate IS NULL AND b.minimumdate IS NULL)
   )
   AND (a.ObjectID = b.ObjectID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old trick with *Nz*:

```
AND (Nz(a.ChangeDate,b.minimumdate) = b.minimumdate)
```